# Cannot mock the constructor of the class in Node.js, TypeScript using Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, constructor, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock the constructor of ClientSecretCredential from the @azure/identity package. The constructor takes 3 string arguments, based on which different kind of exception can be thrown.

```
const credentials: ClientSecretCredential = 
      new ClientSecretCredential("tenant_id", "client_id", "client_secret");
```

Here is the code of my unit test:

```
import {ClientSecretCredential} from "@azure/identity";

describe("ClientSecretCredential described", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });



    describe("Azure identity", ()=> {
        jest.mock("@azure/identity", ()=> {
            return {
                ClientSecretCredential: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
                    throw new Error("Invalid tenant id is provided");
                })
            }
        })

        it("Should throw an error on incorrectly provided tenantId, clientId or clientSecret", ()=>{
           expect(()=>new ClientSecretCredential("some id", "some id", "some id")).rejects.
           toThrowError("Invalid tenant id");
        });
    });
```

I expect to receive the error, which I specified, but it doesn't throw an error for some reason.

Is there any way I can mock and change the inner behaviour of the specified constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `jest.mock()` in module scope will work. It will be hoisted to the top of the file so that it will mock `@azure/identity` when importing it.

Besides, the constructor is not a promise, you don't need to
use `.rejects`.

```js
import { ClientSecretCredential } from '@azure/identity';

jest.mock('@azure/identity', () => {
  return {
    ClientSecretCredential: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('Invalid tenant id is provided');
    }),
  };
});

describe('ClientSecretCredential described', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('Azure identity', () => {
    it('Should throw an error on incorrectly provided tenantId, clientId or clientSecret', () => {
      expect(() => new ClientSecretCredential('some id', 'some id', 'some id')).toThrowError(
        'Invalid tenant id is provided'
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72966538/index.test.js
  ClientSecretCredential described
    Azure identity
      ✓ Should throw an error on incorrectly provided tenantId, clientId or clientSecret (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.097 s, estimated 10 s
```

Comment: Can I mock the constructor inside of the test somehow as well? In this scenario. I would like to change the parameters in the constructor and based on it, I want to return different exceptions